# How to upgrade cockpit-dashboard now that cockpit-235 is out?

Tags: upgrade, cockpit

I allowed apt upgrade to replace cockpit version 233 with version 235, but now the dashboard does not work.

```
apt -a info cockpit-dashboard
Package: cockpit-dashboard
Version: 233-1~ubuntu20.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/admin                                                         
Source: cockpit
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Utopia Maintenance Team <pkg-utopia- 
maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 360 kB
Depends: cockpit-bridge (>= 170.x), cockpit-ws (>= 233- 
1~ubuntu20.04.1), cockpit-ws (<< 233-1~ubuntu20.04.1.1~)
Replaces: cockpit-system (<< 128), cockpit-ws (<< 128)
Homepage: https://cockpit-project.org/
Download-Size: 322 kB
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal- 
backports/universe amd64
Packages
Description: Cockpit remote server dashboard
Cockpit page for showing performance graphs for up to 20 remote 
servers.
```

Does version 235 of dashboard exist yet?  Or do I have to keep waiting for it.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: The information was included: ~ubuntu20.04.1

Comment: @JoeInwap - Hi ... U managed to get yr issue solved. I have used backports to get v 238 but cant seem to get all modules.

Comment: My issue has not been solved.  On Ubuntu 20.04, the current release of cockpit is 238-1~ubuntu20.04.1 is installed.  The version of cockpit dashboard in focal-backports only works with 233.'

Comment: Issue is already solved here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1392040/1569616