# Ubuntu 20.04 - Update to Latest Versions Of Cockpit

Tags: cockpit

I am new to the Ubuntu ecosystem.

On a Focal Fossa (latest lts release ) box, i installed cockpit as below;

```
sudo apt       install   cockpit   cockpit-*
```

These were of version 216

Later I came to know of backports and newer versions ( 238 ) and re-ran the above command as below;

```
sudo apt install cockpit/focal-backports cockpit-*/focal-backports
```

But had errors as below;

```
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-389-ds' was not found
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-ssh' was not found
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-shell' was not found
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-systemd' was not found
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-tuned' was not found
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-users' was not found
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-test-assets' was not found
E: Release 'focal-backports' for 'cockpit-docker' was not found
```

a. How do you guys install the latest versions of cockpit ?

b. Is there another repository ?

c. I know cockpit-docker is superseeded by cockpit-podman but i cant seem to locate it in focal-backports.

d. Is there a command that we can use to list down all packages in a
repository like focal-backports ?
sudo apt search cockpit/focal-backports doesnt work?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @user535733 - Thanks. It doesnt answer a, b or c. Thanks for trying.

Comment: a: Use a newer release of Ubuntu for newer software. Trying to kludge new software onto an older release of Ubuntu is a classic new-user mistake. b: Backports are done by volunteers, so apparently nobody did it. c: No. Most folks don't find a 40,000 item package list useful. That's why there is a Search feature. Look in /var/lib/apt/lists for the "*_Packages" files for the raw source...which is indeed a long, long set of lists.

Comment: @user535733 - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

sudo apt install -t focal-backports cockpit

Version 261 is available and visible in the admin section for focal backports:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-backports/cockpit

Tested and install the upgrade successfully on my end.